# How to ensure record is not saved by two users at the same time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have this class:

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :amount, :invoice_id

  belongs_to :invoice

  validates :amount, :numericality => { :greater_than => 0, :less_than_or_equal_to => :maximum_amount }, :if => "invoice.present?"

  private

  def maximum_amount
    invoice.total if invoice.present?
  end

end
```

The code above works. But how can I make sure that no two users can ever save a new `payment` record at the same time, thereby exceeding the invoice total?

Is it possible to do this at the database level somehow?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is it really possible that two users create a payment at *exactly* the same time? I think when you have two insert statements the database will lock the table and perform the insertions one after another, for example in order to keep auto incremented ids consistent. Can you actually produce such a case? Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: OK, I'm afraid you are right here. In fact two payments at the same time are virtually impossible in my case. The problem I am having is probably a different one, so I decided to [re-phrase my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16528698/how-to-validate-that-payment-can-never-cause-invoice-amount-payable-to-be-less-t).

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your `maximum_amount` function to be something like the following:

```
def maximum_amount
  if invoice.present?
    amt_paid = 0
    invoice.payments.each do |payment|
      amt_paid += payment.amount
    end
    invoice.total - amt_paid
  end
end
```

This isn't at the database level per say, but if a second user attempts to make a payment more than the existing balance it will not validate.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am not sure this is the simplest solution to the problem, though. What I had in mind was some sort of `after_save` callback.