# How to validate that payment can never cause invoice amount payable to be less than zero?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have this class:

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :amount, :invoice_id

  belongs_to :invoice

  validates :amount, :numericality => { :greater_than => 0, :less_than_or_equal_to => :maximum_amount }

  after_save    :update_amount_payable
  after_destroy :update_amount_payable

  private

  def maximum_amount
    invoice.amount_payable
  end

  def update_amount_payable
    invoice.update_amount_payable
  end

end
```

---

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :payments

  after_save :update_amount_payable

  def update_amount_payable
    update_column(:amount_payable_in_cents, new_amount_payable)
  end

  private

  def new_amount_payable
    (total - payments.map(&:amount).sum) * 100
  end

end
```

The code above works. But how can I validate that no payment amount can ever cause `invoice.amount_payable` to be less than `0`?

Especially when multiple payments for the same invoice are possible, this turns out to be tricky.

I've been trying to get my head around this for hours, but to no avail. Maybe an `after` callback to rollback the database can be used here?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is the invoice `amount_payable` updated when a payment is applied?  If so, why isn't this already guaranteed?  Or perhaps are you concerned about concurrent requests being made in parallel?  Please clarify...

Comment: Good points. I added some more code above which will hopefully answer your questions. And yes, I am definitely worried about concurrent requests being made to one `payment` and I haven't found a solution to this problem yet.

Comment: The only solution for concurrency is to have database level constraints or (optimistic/pessimistic) concurrency checks.  ActiveRecord is limited to the current transaction scope and can't tell if the logic has been violated, even when using an `after_` callback.  What DBMS are you using, and what does your `Invoice#update_amount_payable` method look like?

Comment: OK, I posted an excerpt of my `Invoice` model above. During development I am using a simple SQLite database but I might deploy at Heroku later which means ideally my code should work in a Postgres environment as well.

Comment: Would you mind to share your database schema for Invoice and Payment?

Comment: Posted above. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One cross-database solution that will work is to use [optimistic locking](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Optimistic.html).  Essentially, it requires a special `lock_version` column, that is checked whenever an update is made.  If the `lock_version` at the time an UPDATE is called is different than what the model is expecting, it throws an error noting that something outside of this model caused the record to change (thus invalidating the update).  ActiveRecord supports this out of the box, and it will likely suffice for your needs if you don't mind blocking concurrent transactions altogether.

A case that it won't work is where you want to allow concurrent updates.  In this case, you'll need to manually check the result during your update:

```
def update_amount_payable
  new_value = new_amount_payable
  raise "Payment amounts can't be greater than total invoice amount" if new_value < 0
  count = Invoice.where(id: id, amount_payable_in_cents: amount_payable_in_cents).
                  update_all(amount_payable_in_cents: new_value)
  raise ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError.new(self, 'update amount_payable_in_cents') if count != 1
end

private

def new_amount_payable
  (total - payments.sum(:amount)) * 100  # get the amount sum from the database
end
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks so much! This works like a charm, exactly what I needed. Just one more thing. When I enter a value that is too high in the payment view, I get the `Payment amounts can't be greater than total invoice amount` error as expected, however I get it as a (rather ugly) *Action Controller: Exception caught* error. Is it possible to get this as a (more pretty) standard Rails validation error as well?

Comment: At this point in the callback chain, you'll need to rollback the transaction - which can only be done by raising some exception.  You can use `raise ActiveRecord::Rollback` instead, but I'm not sure that's any prettier...  I would recommend using standard validations in tandem with this check, so you'll only be handling it in extreme cases (where validations couldn't catch it).  This means that you can handle the edge-case in a less refined way, while relying on standard validations to catch the vast majority of invalid data more elegantly.

Comment: The optimistic locking will work, but you'll have a race condition in the `if new_value < 0` case, if both threads make if after the "if" statement together.

Comment: @amitkaz: you're right about this. The only way to fix it within the transaction scope would be to perform a check during the update similar to what optimistic locking would have done (but limited to the relevant field). I can't think of any other way around this - updated.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the field names. But given the current database schema try the following code:

**app/models/invoice.rb**

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :payments

  def still_open_amount
    self.amount_payable_in_cents - self.payments.sum('amount_in_cents')
  end
end
```

**app/models/payment.rb**

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :invoice

  validates :amount_in_cents, :numericality => { :greater_than => 0 }

  before_validation :check_all_payments

  private
  def check_all_payments
    if self.new_record?
      if (self.invoice.payments.sum('amount_in_cents') + self.amount_in_cents) > self.invoice.amount_payable_in_cents
        errors.add(:amount, 'the invoice would be overpaid')
      end
    else
      if (self.invoice.payments.sum('amount_in_cents') - self.amount_in_cents_was + self.amount_in_cents) > self.invoice.amount_payable_in_cents
        errors.add(:amount, 'the invoice would be overpaid')
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This will through a validation error if you try to create a overpaying payment:

```
~/Desktop/testapp  ᐅ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.0.0.beta1)
1.9.3-p286 :001 > i = Invoice.create(amount_payable_in_cents: 100)
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (6.8ms)  INSERT INTO "invoices" ("amount_payable_in_cents", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["amount_payable_in_cents", 100], ["created_at", Mon, 13 May 2013 19:23:24 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Mon, 13 May 2013 19:23:24 UTC +00:00]]
   (0.8ms)  commit transaction
 => #<Invoice id: 1, amount_payable_in_cents: 100, created_at: "2013-05-13 19:23:24", updated_at: "2013-05-13 19:23:24"> 
1.9.3-p286 :003 > p1 = i.payments.create(amount_in_cents: 90)
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  Invoice Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "invoices".* FROM "invoices" WHERE "invoices"."id" = ? ORDER BY "invoices"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  SELECT SUM("payments"."amount_in_cents") AS sum_id FROM "payments" WHERE "payments"."invoice_id" = ?  [["invoice_id", 1]]
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "payments" ("amount_in_cents", "created_at", "invoice_id", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["amount_in_cents", 90], ["created_at", Mon, 13 May 2013 19:24:10 UTC +00:00], ["invoice_id", 1], ["updated_at", Mon, 13 May 2013 19:24:10 UTC +00:00]]
   (1.0ms)  commit transaction
 => #<Payment id: 1, invoice_id: 1, amount_in_cents: 90, created_at: "2013-05-13 19:24:10", updated_at: "2013-05-13 19:24:10"> 
1.9.3-p286 :004 > p2 = i.payments.create(amount_in_cents: 20)
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  Invoice Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "invoices".* FROM "invoices" WHERE "invoices"."id" = ? ORDER BY "invoices"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  SELECT SUM("payments"."amount_in_cents") AS sum_id FROM "payments" WHERE "payments"."invoice_id" = ?  [["invoice_id", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction
 => #<Payment id: nil, invoice_id: 1, amount_in_cents: 20, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
1.9.3-p286 :005 > p2.errors
 => #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fd57b8e36d8 @base=#<Payment id: nil, invoice_id: 1, amount_in_cents: 20, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @messages={:amount=>["the invoice would be overpaid"]}> 
1.9.3-p286 :006 >
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Danke! One of my previous solutions looked very much like this and I even got it working at some point. However, Pinny's solution is admittedly much cleaner and much more robust as well I think. Cheers!

Comment: IMO `after_save :update_amount_payable` in the Invoice model is not a good way to tackle this problem. A validation in the Payment model is way cleaner.

Comment: @wintermeyer: Admittedly, trying to catch and handle concurrency issues is not clean by nature as it is the residual effect of a leaky abstraction.  I agree that validations should be the go-to solution for most cases, and use the more messy concurrency checking on top of that for volatile fields (such as caches) that _must_ be correct.  There's no reason they can't both be used here...